# Subclassed UIButton, button press colour

Tags: swift, uibutton, subclass, uicolor

I have subclassed UIButton to create a toggle favourite button which works as expected. The
problem is that the button changes colour briefly when pressed. How can I remove this so that toggle is cleaner, no colour change just image change? My code and gif below. Thanks

```
import UIKit

class FavouriteButton: UIButton {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initButton()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initButton()
    }
    
    func initButton() {
        
        frame.origin = CGPoint.zero
        frame.size = CGSize(width: 32, height: 32)
        tintColor = UIColor.orange
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(FavouriteButton.activateButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func activateButton(){
        
        if currentBackgroundImage == UIImage(systemName: "star") {

            setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"), for: .normal)
            
        } else {
            setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "star"), for: .normal)
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

[image: Favourite button toggle gif]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` to `false` in your init, like this

```
func initButton() {
    
    frame.origin = CGPoint.zero
    frame.size = CGSize(width: 32, height: 32)
    tintColor = UIColor.orange
    adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
    addTarget(self, action: #selector(FavouriteButton.activateButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    
}
```